# Using STL iterators with vectors

Tags: vector, stl, iterator

Hello I'm trying to access an element of a vector containing a bunch of class objects and delete only one of the objects from the vector.

The problem is I don't understand vectors and I can't find any information online which is helpful.

My code:

```
void MyExperiment::deselectSingle() {
Ogre::Vector3 vNewPos = mPickedObj->_getDerivedPosition();
mPickedObj->showBoundingBox( false );
mMoveThis->removeChild( mPickedObj->getName() );
mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->addChild( mPickedObj );
mPickedObj->_setDerivedPosition( vNewPos );

for ( Ogre::SceneNode* it = vObjects.begin(); it < vObjects.end(); it++ ) {
    static std::string objNameStr;
    objNameStr = vObjects.at( *it  )->getName();
    if ( objNameStr == mPickedObj->getName() )
    {
        vObjects.erase( *it );
        break;
    }
}
if ( mMoveThis->numAttachedObjects() == 0 ) bSelected = false;
return;
```

}

I know this code won't work. I've read some stuff online about how to use iterators however when I try some of the things suggested errors crop up. In fact what I have here causes a few errors.

My plan for this function was to iterate through the vObjects vector which contains Ogre::SceneNode pointer elements. If one of the elements matches the mPickedObj's name then I want to remove it from the vector by the .erase() foo. The code above does not work, it was just there as an example though it is what I tried in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What a vector is.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

[A beginner's tutorial on vectors](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm)

Not too hard at all - take the time to understand the STL collections, and you'll have a resource that fits for 80% of the things you need in the future.

The only 'special' thing you need to know for a vector, as opposed to the other collections, is that erasing an element in the middle of a vector will cause the rest of the elements to move down to close the gap you just made.

Comment: Erasing from the middle of a `std::deque` also causes some elements to "move down to close the gap"

Comment: Your 80% estimate is too low. And erasing from the beginning of a vector is even worse than erasing from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing the vector in rightway before forloop;
but in initialization part of for loop: why reinitialized it again?

```
Ogre::SceneNode* it = vObjects.begin()
```

Iterator 'll be initialized to begin() [first element] and loops through its item until it reaches end.

```
 (it=vObjects.begin();it!=vObjects.end();it++)
```

you should not compare it normally with ' < ' operator. it ends when it reaches end [i.e end position exclusive]

i'm not sure what is vObjects.erase(*it) ...

But if you want to dereference an element in vector do

```
vector[i] //if ith element already present if not it causes segmentation fault [can use it like normal array]
vector.at(i)  //safe and if doesn't exist throws exception
```

for deleting an element you pass the iterator position for erase(it) to delete it; if element is at last can use pop_back().

Comment: Its been created and initialized twice because that's old code mixed with new code. I just left the old iterator in there because I was too lazy to remove it though I should have. You are correct. The truth is I did not and still do not know how to iterate through my vector of scene node pointers. My plan was: iterate through the vObjects scene node pointer vector, and if one of the elements matches the mPickedObj's name remove it from the vector by erase() and break since we only want to do this once and on that current element.

Comment: I edited the thing to make it more clear and remove everything that should have been.